# encapsulation, accessor C# vs Java

Tags: java, c#, encapsulation, accessor

A quick question about encapsulation and accessor in `C#` vs `Java`.
Is this code in `C#` equivalent to the one in Java below?

**C#**:

```
class MyClass{

    public string var1 {get; private set;}
    public int var2 {get; private set;}

    public MyClass(string aString, int anInt){
        this.var1= aString;
        this.var2=anInt;
    }

}
```

**java**

```
//Java
class MyClass{

    private String var1;
    private int var2;

    public MyClass(String aString, int anInt){
        this.var1= aString;
        this.var2=anInt;
    }

    public String getVar1(){
        return this.var1;
    }

    public void setVar1(int anInt){
         this.var1 = anInt;
    }

    public int getVar2(){
        return this.var2;
    }

    public void setVar2(String aString){
         this.var2 = aString;
    }

}
```

I'm coming from the `java` world, not sure about the accessor shortening in `C#`.

Comment: `void int` and `void String` are not a valid return types...

Comment: ;) funny bad habits when writing code witout an IDE, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in the C# code you've got private setters - in your Java code they're public.

The C# equivalent to the Java code would be:

```
public string Var1 { get; set; }
public int Var2 { get; set; }
```

(I've changed the names to follow .NET naming conventions - properties are PascalCased.)

Comment: OK I See now, was a bit scarred to declare public the var despite the setter

Comment: @JimC: You're not declaring a public *variable* - just a public *property*. The backing field is still private.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't have a public set field in either to be honest.

What is the benefit of having a public mutator? I've very rarely seen a reason to have a public mutator.

Comment: The C# version does not have a public mutator.

Comment: I know. I was just making a general statement. Java one does and if he makes it get; set; in C# to match then they'll both have public and probably shouldn't be.